# C# Convert BLOB to jpg, resize, then back to BLOB

Tags: c#, image, asp.net

I am trying to convert a `BLOB` that is stored in a database to a `JPG` and then I need to display it on an `html form` in a `C#` application.

A little backstory first - this is an older web app that was designed to take a `JPG` (photo) that was stored as a path in the database, resize it, then show as a `BLOB`. This functionality needs to stay in place, but now one of the systems is changing and the photo is going to be stored in the database as a `BLOB` instead of a path to a photo (\servername\images\xyz.jpg).

One system still needs the image to be resized then sent back as a `BLOB` to display. The other systems that call this web-app will need the `BLOB` converted to a `JPG` to display.

The code below works, but I think it might have put an unnecessary load on the server, because this morning the system was laggy and some features were impossible to use. I have a feeling that the `.Save` is the troublemaker here since I am calling it twice. I know the image doesn't need to be saved anywhere physically, as long as the web-app can call and have it display to the site. Is there anything I can change here to skip saving an image on the server and just display it so it doesn't use up a ton of resources?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   byte[] byteImage = null;
    string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];
    string imageFile = "\\\\server\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web-app\\images\\" + ID+ ".jpg";
    string server = Request.ServerVariables["server_name"];
    var serverNameList = db.Servers.Select(x => x.ServerName).ToList();

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp", connection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    sqlCommand.Parameters["@ID"].Value = ID;
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();                               

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        byteImage = (byte[])dr["BLOB"];
    }

    if (byteImage != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteImage))
        {
            //saving to jpg image
            Image img = new Bitmap(ms);
            img.Save(imageFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.CacheControl = "public";
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0));
            Response.ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
               
            if (serverNameList.Contains(server)) // if user is coming from a specific server, resize the image then send back
            {
                byte[] resizedImage = GetResizedImage(imageFile, 300, 400);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(resizedImage, 0, resizedImage.Length);
            }
            else // skip resize and show image as jpg
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(byteImage);
            }
        }
    }
    else // image is null
    {
        imageFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "PERSON.GIF";
    }         
}
    
private byte[] GetResizedImage(string path, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(path);
    double height1 = bitmap1.Height;
    double width1 = bitmap1.Width;
    double num = 1.0;
    if (width > 0)
        num = width / width1;
    else if (height > 0)
    num = height / height1;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap((int)(width1 * num), (int)(height1 * num));
    bitmap2.SetResolution(150f, 150f);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2);
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmap1, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(num * width1), (int)(num * height1)), new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)width1, (int)height1), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    bitmap2.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview! I hope you get some good feedback.

### Absolute paths

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];
string imageFile = "\\\\server\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web-app\\images\\" + ID+ ".jpg";
```

This has a few issues. First, it's typical for a server to be in a "jail" where it shouldn't have access to the filesystem at large, and should only access data from its own local directory. This is for security purposes. Though I haven't done this in a long time, it seems the ASP.NET way of safely accessing such paths is [MapPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8).

Second: it's crucially important that you do some validation on ID. In its current state a hacker could easily construct a path navigation exploit where the ID contains `..\..\..` (etc) to explore the rest of the filesystem if the server is misconfigured.

### Managing your connection

If `connection` is an [SqlConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), it implements `IDisposable`, and as such you should put it in a [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). The same is true of `SqlCommand`.

### Add-with-value

You should prefer [AddWithValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) over a separated `Add`/`.Value` assignment here;

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@ID"].Value = ID;
```

### Read-in-loop

This:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    byteImage = (byte[])dr["BLOB"];
}
```

should probably not use a loop. Since it seems you expect only one row returned,

- `Read()` once;
- assert that it returned `true`;
- assign `byteImage`;
- `Read()` again;
- assert that it returned `false`.

### Streamed image creation

`GetResizedImage` creates a memory stream. It should not. `Response` already has an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream?view=netframework-4.8), and you should be writing to that directly. The one thing to double-check with this approach is that `Content-Length` is still set correctly, which is probably only possible if `BufferOutput` is enabled.

### Avoiding files

As to your original question, which I never really addressed:

> Is there anything I can change here to skip saving an image on the server and just display it so it doesn't use up a ton of resources?

Yes! As long as you get an image from the database, you always `Save()` it to the disc. However, this file is only used if the server name is approved. Move your save within the name check, and fewer cases will require disc I/O.

Even further: if this is the only code that touches that file, that file should not exist at all and you should not be doing a round trip to the disc. Once you have your `img`, pass that to `GetResizedImage` instead of a path string.

### Bug?

There is a mechanism here:

```
imageFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "PERSON.GIF";
```

which looks like it's supposed to substitute a default image if none is returned from the database. However, that file is never used. This logic needs to be rearranged so that it is. If you get back a null from the database, load this file into your byteImage.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make all the updates you suggested and the systems are working beautifully together. Can't even tell there is another call there to resize the images. :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider not using System.Drawing to manipulate images in ASP.NET:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use
> within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes
> from within one of these application types may produce unexpected
> problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time
> exceptions.[1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing#remarks)

An alternative could be the new [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) library currently in pre-release or [ImageScaler](https://github.com/saucecontrol/PhotoSauce).

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into using either one of those in the future. I'm not a fan of using this outdated code either. :)